# Cauchy Schwarz inequality for surface integrals?

Tags: surface-integrals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

For square integrable functions $f, g$, the [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) inequality says,

$$ \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f^2(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g^2(x)dx\right) $$

I was wondering if there was some surface integral equivalent to this theorem. For instance, suppose $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is some ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, would the following "Cauchy-Schwarz" inequality still work?

$$ \left(\int_{\partial B}fgdS\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_{\partial B}f^2dS\right)\left(\int_{\partial B}g^2dS\right) $$

where $\partial B$ represents the surface of $B$. I haven't had luck finding this in literature anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general measure $\mu$ (positive measure) one has $\|fg\|_{L^{1}(\mu)}\leq\|f\|_{L^{2}(\mu)}\|g\|_{L^{2}(\mu)}$.

Comment: Search Holder's inequality in Wikipedia for details.

Comment: In this case, is our measure the surface measure, dS?

Comment: Yes, the surface measure is a positive measure.